# How can I duplicate items in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you duplicate items quickly in Minecraft? I have tried to drop it and then getting off of the world, and then getting back in, but it didn't work out too well. Nothing got duplicated. I just can't duplicate them. It doesn't work at all.

Comment: Could you clarify?

Comment: are you talking about admin commands to give yourself items? or a bug/exploit to duplicate certain items?

Comment: Creative mode is the fastest and easiest way to duplicate items.

Answer (score 8):

Duplicating items is not possible in Minecraft (besides doing things like farming to 'duplicate' carrots etc.). There have been bugs in the past that would allow you to duplicate items with certain hacks, but these were all fixed reasonably quickly. There have been, and are not (to anyone's knowledge) any long-standing item duplication bugs in Minecraft.

Comment: And there never will be. Dupe bugs are pretty high on the list of 'things that will get patched immediately'

Answer (score 4):

It is possible in survival mode, but you will probably need an **old version** of Minecraft. Here's how it's done by [speedrunners](https://forum.speeddemosarchive.com/post/minecraft_planning_293.html):

> 1. Drop the stuff you want to dupe on the floor
> 2. Save+Quit
> 3. Go back into the game
> 4. Pick up the stuff
> 5. after 2 seconds, alt+f4 close the game
> 6. Start the game again, pick up the stuff a second time
>
> This only duplicates your stuff, and therefore the other glitch might be better. But I think there was some reason not to use it, more than just that "your" version got patched relatively soon after 1.0, bismuth runs 1.2.4 iirc.

As mentioned, duplication bugs usually get fixed very quickly and usually none are found in the latest version.